# How to detect to view visibility(80% or so) in a recycler view like Youtube Autoplay news feed plays video when ~80 is visible

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scroll, youtube, visibility

How to detect to view visibility(80% or so) in a recycler view like Youtube Autoplay news feed plays the video when ~80 is visible. And the video playback stops on a scroll and starts to play on idle state, but initially, if the video is in playing state it continues in that state even in scrolling state until it is ~80 visible after which it is stopped, so how is this done.
Ideas and examples are appreciated.

What I tried, use the recycler views onChildDetached method but it triggers the event only when the complete view goes out of the visible screen area.
Thanks.

Comment: compare views height and views visible height(getGlobalVisibleRect)

Comment: This needs to be done during scrolling itself, so how to trigger something like that. View can go out of view any time during scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You can play the first fully visible item like this. If there is a possibility of 2 complete visible items and you want them both to play instead of "findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition" you can iterate through layoutManagers child and compare their visible heights with actual heights.

```
val scrollListener = object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            val layoutManager = (recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager)
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
            val firstItem = layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
            //get the item at position fistItem and play
        }
    }
    yourRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener)
```